# Sharing my auth token between Asp.Net 3.5 and Asp.Net 4.0?

Tags: asp.net, forms, .net-4.0, forms-authentication, asp.net-3.5

I have two sets of web applications, one set running under Asp.Net 3.5 and one set running Asp.Net 4.0. Both are hosted in IIS 6. I need to use a shared forms authentication (via the 3.5 app) to authenticate and authorize both the 3.5 and 4.0 applications. However I'm unable to get this done. So far I have

- Made sure the `<machineKey>` configuration section is identical on all applications.
- Set my providers up identically: pointing to the same database.
- I've even tried using aspnet:UseLegacyEncryption [per this post](http://forums.asp.net/t/1619902.aspx/1).

So far nothing I have tried has worked. EXCEPT when I switch the "3.5" application to run under ver. 4.0. Then both sites are able to share the auth token just fine. Unfortunately for me this is not an option in production.

Obviously there is something different between 3.5 and 4.0 but I can't figure out what it is. What am I missing? Has anyone else come across this? What did you do to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest checking for updates to .NET framework (3.5 & 4) on the machine you're working on - I'm stuck with the same issue myself and this is what I am currently trying to resolve it.

I've read that certain updates made changes to the way auth tokens are created. Looks like my local version 4 was updated, but 3.5 was not - so as far as 3.5 is concerned the tokens generated by .net4 are not acceptable.

Fingers crossed!

Comment: Having spent some time downloading and installing updates, forms authentication now works on my project.

I hope it solves the problem for others too! It's taken me a while to get here! :D

Comment: Dis your updates work? I've been able to resolve this on my local machine but it's still not working on the server.

Comment: Installing the updates worked for me on my local machine. Server environment was up to date anyway so authentication works there too. Does your server have the same updates applied?